# Переобразование несколько массивов в один

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте! 
Есть массив типа:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Test2
        )

)
```

Мне нужно весь этот массив переобразовать в один массив, **при этом** чтобы содержимое title стало ключом, а содержимое id - значением.

Т.е. нужен массив такого типа:

```
Array
(
    'Test' => 1,
    'Test2' => 2
)
```

---

Пробовал такой вариант - собственно, как и ожидалось записывает лишь последнюю ячейку в массив:

```
$selector = [];

foreach ($categories as $category){

    $selector = [
        $category['title'] => $category['id']
    ];
}
```

Пробовал несколько других, но в итоге всё же образуется новый массив.

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: $selector[] = [
        $category['title'] => $category['id']
    ];     Или  arra_push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо переписыванния значения `$selector` добавляйте новый подмассив:

```
$selector = [];

foreach ($categories as $category){
    $selector[$category['title']] = $category['id'];
}
```

Если `title` будет повторяться, то в `$selector` останется только последнее значение